# How do I change thedefault folder inExcel's Link popup window

Tags: excel, directory, hyperlink, default

Let me set the stage.
There's text in a cell in an Excel spreadsheet. I click on the cell then click on the Link in the Insert tab. A popup comes on the screen titled Edit Hyperlink. On that screen is a Look In folder. I want to change the DEFAULT Folder discplayed. That way, each time I have a project so that its easier to do a bunch of Links and not have to change the starting folder for looking every time.

Let's be clear. I know I can change the Look In folder nce the poipup screen is displayed. I want to change the folder in Excel so that when the Edit Hyperlink window appears,  it has the folder displayed that had the file I want to link to. I want to avoid navigating to the folder every time I want to inster a link in the near future. And then some time down the road, I want to change the default displayed Look In folder again.
Thank you.

As I mentioned before I searched for an answer on other site.. I looked in the al lthe pulldown options after clicking the Fuke link in the Excel ribbon. I paied cloe attentin to the Options display. I could find nother related to changing the default start folder for thids Hyperlink function.

Comment: Had a quick look around and general consensus seems to be that you can't change it.  [change default folder location for hyperlinks](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/change-default-folder-location-for-hyperlinks.305273/)

Comment: Having said that you can change the [base address for links in the workbook.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/work-with-links-in-excel-7fc80d8d-68f9-482f-ab01-584c44d72b3e) but I don't think that's what you're after - you just have to enter the filename and it will link to that location, but change the base address and it will change it for those file name only links.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I too thought something under Options or then under Advamces Settings wou

Comment: It got changed once. It isn't a high level folder under my user ID. that folder is under Users/myID/Folder/Subfolder/Subsubfolder So if it got changed from whatever is the syetm default to this, it can be changed again. Unless MS in its infinite wisdom took away that option and you're stuck with whatver folder you're pointing to at the moment. I doubt that scenario.

Comment: I respect and appreciate everyone's help BUT One more inportant note: the path to the folder is NOT on the C drive but on the D drive where I keep all my active data.  D:\Users\myID\Folder\Subfolder\Subsubfolder NOT on the C drive but on the D. Surely the default is pointing to a folder on the C drive. So if it got changed from whatever is the syetm default to this, it can be changed again. Who has an in with MS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was asked by the site's moderator to clarify my question. On Excel's Insert Tab is a "Link" option. A popup window appears to navigate to a file (or other options but I'm interested in going to a file. In the center of this pop-up is a "Look In" with a starting Folder. I want to change the default starting Folder. It was changed once as it does point to a personal folder that is recent compared to the life of the Excel Product. That's the option for adding a link to a cell that does not have a link. I am asking for help on how to change the default folder. It was done once in that option.

Comment: Continuing: If a cell has a link already associated with it a similar Edit Lik pop-up appears. It is different in that the Look In folder displayed by this widow shows me a folder that is again one of my own folders, not the system default and not the same as the one displayed by the empty link cell. Again, the Look In folder is not an Excel chosen folder but one that was changed a at some point. How was it changed is my question to the community.